# Mongo. How to count array of objects from single document?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I tried but I can't to make the query to count e.g.
Let's assume that we have a document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("24926523r3423423423423rr"),
    "name" : "My super team",
    "stadium" : "Capital",
    "players" : [
            {
                    "name"    : "PlayerName1",
                    "number"  : "1",
                    "country" : "BRA"
            },
            {
                    "name"    : "PlayerName2",
                    "number"  : "2",
                    "country" : "FRA"
            },
            {
                    "name"    : "PlayerName3",
                    "number"  : "3",
                    "country" : "BRA"
            },
            {
                    "name"    : "PlayerName4",
                    "number"  : "4",
                    "country" : "ARG"
            },
            {
                    "name"    : "PlayerName5",
                    "number"  : "5",
                    "country" : "GER"
            },
            {
                    "name"    : "PlayerName6",
                    "number"  : "6",
                    "country" : "BRA"
            },
    ]
}
```

And question is how to count all 'BRA' players from team 'My super team' (I have a lot of teams in collection. Any ideas ? I tried some combination of $size and aggregate but I failed. Or maybe better if you have a tip how to deal with that query using Morphia ?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet thanks that was very helpfull